# parse json data and show in list view

Tags: android, json, android-listview

my project is get json data from server and display in list view put when run the code not work my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, this.datadrinks()));

}
public ArrayList<String> datadrinks()
{
    ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        URL twitter = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:50667/expression%20web4/GetAllDrinkItems.ashx");
        URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                tc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONObject ja = new JSONObject(line);
            JSONArray jobj=ja.getJSONArray("lstDrinkItems");

        for (int i = 0; i < jobj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = jobj.getJSONObject(i);
            listItems.add(jo.getString("Name"));
        } 
        }
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listItems;

    }
}
```

Comment: what problem are you getting?

Comment: where is the result u getting?? if u show the result the parsing problem can be find??

Comment: refer the following link [showing jsondata in listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an obvious error in your code.

But you have a huge problem in the design. You are making a server request on the UI thread. You should never do that. On newer versions of Android you are not even allowed to do that.

You should use instead a specialized class like [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

- `doInBackground` : make the request and parse the response
- `onPostExecute` : populate the listView

Hope this helps you in your future projects!